# Endlessloop while clearing queue with pointers

Tags: c++

I have a structure LastTimeOn that has next pointer to the same structure. I don't want to introduce the back pointer. I am struggling with clearing this structure, can u help me? On pump can be turned on many times and then the structure grows like this pump1->lastTimeOn->next->next->next. The program runs in endless loop REM2REM3REM4REM2REM3REM4 etc:

```
class Pump {
public:
    LastTimeOn *lastTimeOn;
    Pump();
};

class LastTimeOn{
public:
    unsigned int dayOfWeek;
    unsigned int hour;
    unsigned int minute;
    LastTimeOn(unsigned int minute1, unsigned int hour1, unsigned int dayOfWeek1);
    LastTimeOn *next;
};

void clearLastTimeOn(Pump *pump1) {
    Serial.print("REM1");
    while (pump1->lastTimeOn != NULL) {
        LastTimeOn *lastTimeOn = pump1->lastTimeOn;
        Serial.print("REM2");
        while (lastTimeOn->next != NULL) {
            Serial.print("REM3");

            lastTimeOn = lastTimeOn->next;

        }
        Serial.print("REM4");
        delete lastTimeOn;
        if (pump1->lastTimeOn->next == NULL){
            Serial.print("REM4a");
            delete pump1->lastTimeOn;
            pump1->lastTimeOn = NULL;
        }
    }
    Serial.print("REM5");
}
```

I create new data like this:

```
lastTimeOn->next = new LastTimeOn(minute, hour, dayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can u think, there is no clearLastTimeOn body? I just need implement clearing method for the quoted LastTimeOn structure. It belongs to Pump structure but it doesnt matter..

Comment: I guess you're writing something for arduino-like. So I would recommend don't use approach that you marked as answer :). Actually, for any other platform that's also not a good idea... Use Jorge's answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LastTimeOn{
public:
    unsigned int dayOfWeek;
    unsigned int hour;
    unsigned int minute;
    LastTimeOn(unsigned int minute1, unsigned int hour1, unsigned int dayOfWeek1);
    LastTimeOn();
    LastTimeOn *next;
    ~LastTimeOn() { delete this->next; }
};

void clearLastTimeOn(Pump *pump1) {
    if (pump1)
       delete pump1->lastTimeOn;
}
```

Comment: But isnt it a memory leak? What with object pump1->lastTimeOn->next->next ? will the most far away object be removed from memory?

Comment: The destructor of LastTimeOn would take care of those

Comment: Great approach to get stack overflow exception

Comment: What I don't like about this is if you remove an item from the list, you better remember to set `next` to `nullptr` before deleting it or you just obliterated the list. Might be a good candidate for `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick idea I got... You pass your pump1->lastTimeOn to this:

```
void clearLastTimeOn(LastTimeOn* lastTimeOn)
{
    while (lastTimeOn != nullptr)
    {
        LastTimeOn* current = lastTimeOn;
        lastTimeOn = lastTimeOn->next;
        delete current;
    }
}
```

And after that you set pump1->lastTimeOn to nullptr.